# VBA SQL update/insert to local table using values from form

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, upsert

I am trying to update a row in a local table stored in access (or insert a new row if that ID doesn't already exist) using values populated in a form by the user. I am writing it in VBA using SQL. Here is the code:

```
Public Function update_table()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (id1 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156] AND id2 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158]))" & _
    "INSERT INTO table1 ( id1, id2, id3, id4, id5 )" & _
    "VALUES ([Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text160]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text201]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text166])" & _
"Else" & _
    "Update table1" & _
    "SET id4 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text201], id5 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text166]" & _
    "WHERE (id1 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156] AND id2 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158])"


DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)


End Function
```

The code returns the following error message :

Run-time error '3129', invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access SQL does not support `if` statements, only [`iif`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) statements.

As such, you'll likely need to implement the logic within VBA, e.g.:

```vb
Public Function update_table()
    Dim strSQL As String

    If DCount("*","table1","id1 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156] AND id2 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158]") = 0 Then
        strSQL = _
        "INSERT INTO table1 ( id1, id2, id3, id4, id5 ) " & _
        "VALUES ([Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text160]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text201]," & _
        "[Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text166])"
    Else
        strSQL = _
        "UPDATE table1 " & _
        "SET id4 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text201], id5 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text166] " & _
        "WHERE (id1 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text156] AND id2 = [Forms]![Study Info Cleaned]![Text158])"
    End If
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Function
```

There are a few other issues:

- `stringSQL` is a typo, since you initially define your variable as `strSQL`.
- `DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)` parentheses should not surround the argument since the expression is not part of another expression.

Comment: This worked great thank you. Do you mind elaborating on your final issue regarding the parentheses. Do you only surround the argument if the expression is nested?

Comment: @RonanGarrison You're most welcome. [Here's the official explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code) concerning when to use parentheses in VBA - I hope this helps.